# Styling issue caused by tailwind ring in AsyncPaginate

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, react-select

The smaller input box of blue color appears in the input bar of AsyncPaginate as soon as i click in it. As soon as i comment the tailwind configuration file, the inner box goes away. Tailwinds classes such as `border-none focus:ring-transparent`doesn't remove the color of the inner box as well. You can see the image and code below
[image: A small box that expands when i start typing]

```
import { AsyncPaginate } from "react-select-async-paginate";
const Search = () => {
const [search, setSearch] = useState(null);
return (
<div className="border-transparent">
   <AsyncPaginate  
   placeholder="Search for city"
   debounceTimeout={600}
   value={search}
   className="border-none focus:ring-transparent"
   // styles={style}
   onChange={handleOnChange}
   styles={{
   control: (baseStyles, state) => ({
   ...baseStyles,
   borderColor: state.isFocused ? 'orange' : 'red',
   ring: 0, // Remove the ring effect
   }),
   }}
   loadOptions={loadOptions}
   >
   </AsyncPaginate>
</div>
)
}
export default Search
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issued resolved by setting strategy to both 'base'and 'class'.

```
plugins: [
  require("@tailwindcss/forms")({
    strategy: 'base', // only generate global styles
    strategy: 'class', // only generate classes
  }),
],
```